# SQL Left Outer Join Conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, case

I'm running a very conditional query in MS SQL. I've inherited this database and it's structure can't be changed. Due to poor design the one field (PlantName) can either house a string or a int that is used to reference a string in another table(SoilSpecies). I'm trying to keep this all down in one query, and I'm trying to bring the SoilSpecies table in on a Left Outer Join. The problem I can't compare the PlantName strings in many of the rows to the Int primary key on SoilSpecies.

And Example would be:

"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'rose' to data type int."

I was wondering if it was possible conditionally set the contents of a field to '0' if it's not already on INT for the purposes of a join.

```
select distinct sv.sampleno, sv.plantName,
sv.tests, sv.plantNameOther, sv.originalsubmitContact, 
sv.sampletype, sv.test_foliar, sv.form, 
COALESCE (ci.clname, BTE_Customer.name) AS clname,
o.officename,  

CAST(di.id as BIT) as DIAGIMAGES,

sv.PlantLocation,
CASE 
WHEN (sv.form = 'soils') THEN sv.plantName
ELSE NULL
END
AS sampleType,


CASE
WHEN (sv.form = 'soils') THEN ss.name
ELSE NULL
END
AS ssName

from searchview sv  
left outer join clientinfo  ci on 
    sv.clientid = ci.clientid 
left outer join  BTE_Customer on 
    BTE_Customer.BTE_ID = sv.BTE_ID
left outer join  BTE_CustomerProperty on 
    sv.BTE_ID = BTE_CustomerProperty.BTE_ID AND sv.Property_ID = BTE_CustomerProperty.Property_ID
left outer join offices o on
    sv.officeID = o.officeID
left outer join reply r on 
    sv.sampleno = r.sampleno
left outer join diagnosticimages di on 
    sv.sampleno = di.sampleno
left outer join SoilsSpecies ss on
    (sv.plantname = ss.name) or (sv.plantname = ss.SpeciesID) 



WHERE (not sv.sampleno = 0)

and form in ('Soils','Plants')




AND (ci.clname like '%NAME%' or BTE_Customer.name like '%NAME%')
```

Comment: Could you possibly add a view to the database?

Comment: I know you're saying you want it in "one" query, but what about joining together two queries with a `union`: One referencing plant strings (no join) and one that does the join with `soilSpecies`?

Comment: A view could have worked I'm sure. And as far as a union, I'm not sure how that would work with my server side script (CFML) so I was avoiding it. The answer I posted will work for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to handle this but it worked. I was simply able to convert the INT field from the outer table to a NVARCHAR and compare it back to string field in the original table. This way I get nulls in the rows that don't match up. Which is the logic I was looking for, and I just check for Nulls later.

I replaced my last LEFT OUTER JOIN with the following:

```
left outer join SoilsSpecies ss on
    (CONVERT(nvarchar,ss.speciesID) = sv.plantname)
```

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.  I was under the impression you wanted to do the join in either case (whether PLANTNAME is numeric or alpha).  My suggestion would be useful in that case, but if you only want the join when your PLANTNAME is numeric, then your solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You need a short-circuiting operator (CASE) to avoid the type mismatches.  I haven't really tested it, but you might try something like the below.  Change your join to SoilsSpecies to the below:

```
left outer join SoilsSpecies ss on
    1 = case when isnumeric(sv.plantname) = 1 then 
            case when sv.plantname = ss.SpeciesID then 1 end
        when sv.plantname = ss.name then 1
        else 0
        end
```